# Can I create a Live DVD of my currently running Debian system?

Tags: debian, livecd, system-recovery

Can I create a live CD of my currently running Debian setup? (Debian 9.1 with KDE with all the configurations I made, all the packages I installed and some files.)

How can I do that?

And in addition can I use this or some related way to do a system restore?

[It seems that these things are already possible for Ubuntu with the "systemback" tool](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-live-system-iso-for-your-ubuntu-based-linux-machines-using-systemback/).

Answer (score 0):

Prepare  environment.
 - Copy the Source system to the target directory.
 - Chroot into the new system and make some modifications.
 - Prepare The CD directory tree.
 - Build the CD/DVD

Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall) , to see exactly what you should do in each step. it will do the job.